# How can I filter social traffic under Social in Google Analytics channels report?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

In Google Analytics, under Acquisition > All Traffic > Channels report traffic from facebook and one referral page is grouped. How can I send this traffic under Social and Referral?

Here's an example of the URL that I created with URL builder:
http://www.kariyerakademi.net/finans-uzmanlik-egitimi?utm_source=facebook&utm_campaign=finans_uzmanlik_egitimi_ekim&utm_medium=post

[image]

Comment: Is this traffic from paid social posts?

Comment: No it's not paid. We create and post this content.

Comment: I would suggest the course of action I answered below. This will list the traffic as social.

Comment: Your UTM tagged URLs appear in the "Acquisition" -> "Campaigns" -> "All Campaigns" report.  Tagging URLs does not change the default channel grouping.

Comment: Is there any way that I can save them from grouping under (other) default channel? Maybe advanced filters but I don't know which one to apply?